# Copying Specific Columns to Excel while Filtering Blank Rows

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

*I manage the attendance system of cadets for a military function. Within this, it is required when they have an excused absence to have a valid reason verified by leadership to ensure they meet attendance requirements.*

The system I have currently is a Microsoft form that uses Office Scripts to copy data from the form. I don't particularly need a script, I more or less need either that or an excel formula that works.

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3pVP.png)
[Where it Needs to be Copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyZOl.png).

Data from columns G (Names), H (Time Selection), and O (Comments) are what I'd like to copy, ***but only if the row in column O has data that isn't blank***. Ideally this would happen automatically, so other people do not need to enter anything.

I've tried some scripting to no use. Most of the time the formulas I use cause formatting issues, or just plain do not work. The filter function does not work with merged cells and I cannot change the size of the cells. Ideally, I want to keep this organized on this sheet and not a separate sheet. VBA is a no go since I cannot integrate macros with MS form-based excel docs.

Comment: What merged cells? Please share the script and formulas you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.